# The delay between the two MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two media elements on myForm. I upload the same video, but between MediaElement1 and MediaElement2 delay of about a second.

```
MediaElement1.Source = new Uri("D:\\test.avi", UriKind.Relative);
MediaElement2.Source = new Uri("D:\\test.avi", UriKind.Relative);
MediaElement1.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
MediaElement2.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
MediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
MediaElement2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
```

xaml

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement1" Margin="0,0,5,126" />  
<MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement2" Margin="0,0,15,126"/>
```

Why is there a delay and how to get around?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added a question

Comment: Are you holding the MediaElements in anything e.g. Canvas?

Comment: <Grid> <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement1" Margin="0,0,5,126" /> <MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement2" Margin="0,0,15,126"/> </Grid>

Comment: Not sure you can get around the delay. I mean you can use a Task to start each one so they are a-synchronous but in the end they need to join back to the UI thread which will cause a delay. Might be worth trying to see if the delay is sub-second.

Comment: Then why the delay is only the first viewing, if I run the preview again that there is no delay?

Comment: Have you tried setting the LoadedBehaviour="Manual"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works without delay, it was necessary to add a stop command.

```
        private static OpenFileDialog OpenFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd;
            ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.AddExtension = true;
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.*";
            ofd.Filter = "media (*.*)|*.*";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
            return ofd;
        }

        private void loadm1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = OpenFile();
            M1.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName, UriKind.Relative);
            M1.Position = TimeSpan.Zero;
            M1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop;
        }

        private void loadm2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = OpenFile();
            M2.Source = new Uri(ofd.FileName, UriKind.Relative);
            M2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Stop;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            M1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
            M2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
        }

        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            M1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Pause;
            M2.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Pause;
        }
```

xaml

```
 <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="252*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="265*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <MediaElement x:Name="M1" Margin="0,0,5,126" />
        <MediaElement x:Name="M2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,15,126"/>
        <Button x:Name="loadm1" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,99" Width="75" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="loadm1_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="loadm2" Content="Load" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,99" Width="75" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="loadm2_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" Margin="10,0,20,20" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="btnStart_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnPause" Content="Pause" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,289,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnPause_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```